# Falling ASCII balls

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, physics

### Input

You are given a 2D map with balls and ground in it.
It looks like this:

```
  1         5          2
                 3
     4


__________________________
```

Each number is a ball, and the `_` is ground level. The underscore `_` character is not allowed in any other line than ground level line. There are only spaces, newlines and digits `0-9` allowed above ground level. You cannot assume that last line is the ground level - empty lines below ground level are allowed. You can also add spaces, to fill empty lines, if that does help you.

Balls can have numbers from `0` to `9`, can be placed above each other, but not under ground. The ball's numbers will be unique.

Assume that each character is **one meter**.

[Get map from pastebin!](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17848771/)

[Test case 1](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17854204/) - should output something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17860519/)

[Test case 2](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17854273/) - should produce same results as first map

### Challenge

Your challenge is to read a map like that from a file or from `stdin` — you are allowed to use `cat balls.txt | ./yourexecutable` — and output velocity of each ball when it hits the ground.

Here's the formula for velocity:
[image]

Assume that `h` is the line number difference between the ground's line number, and the ball's line number, and that `g` equals `10m/s^2`.

### Output

You should output each balls number and velocity in `m/s` at ground level.
For example `N - Vm/s`, where `N` is ball number and `V` is its velocity.
You can also output an array if you want.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Test cases with no expected result are not test cases

Comment: @edc65 I added expected results to the question

Comment: Is it okay if I take the directory as input from the user as part of the program?

Comment: @Dopapp What do you mean exactly?

Comment: See my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83802/42854).

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
95\16\5B#fG&X>1)b- 20*X^h
```

Input is a 2D char array with `;` as row separator:

```
['  1         5          2  ';'                 3        ';'     4                    ';'                          ';'                          ';'__________________________']
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTVcMTZcNUIjZkcmWD4xKWItIDIwKlheaA&input=WycgIDEgICAgICAgICA1ICAgICAgICAgIDIgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgMyAgICAgICAgJzsnICAgICA0ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX18nXQ) Or [include an initial `t` in the code](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDk1XDE2XDVCI2ZHJlg-MSliLSAyMCpYXmg&input=WycgIDEgICAgICAgICA1ICAgICAgICAgIDIgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgMyAgICAgICAgJzsnICAgICA0ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX18nXQ) to display the map for greater clarity.

Here are the other test cases: [first](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTVcMTZcNUIjZkcmWD4xKWItIDIwKlheaA&input=WycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnICAxICAgICAgICAgNSAgICAgICAgICAyICAnOycgIDYgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAzICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgNCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnICAgICA3ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7J19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fJ10), [second](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTVcMTZcNUIjZkcmWD4xKWItIDIwKlheaA&input=WycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnICAxICAgICAgICAgNSAgICAgICAgICAyICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDMgICAgICAgICc7JyAgICAgNCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJzsnICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICc7J19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fX19fJzsnICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICdd).

#### Explanation

```
95\      % Take input implicitly. Modulo 95: convert to numbers and map '_' into 0
16\      % Modulo 16: map space into 0 and digit chars into corresponding numbers
5B#f     % Find row indices and values of nonzero entries
G        % Push input again
&X>      % Index of maximum of each column. This finds character '_'
1)       % Get first value (they are all equal)
b        % Bubble row indices of numbers up in the stack
-        % Subtract to get distance from each number to the ground
20*X^    % Multiply by 20, take sqrt. This gives the velocity values
h        % Horizontally concat numbers and velocities. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 7):

## C, <strike>125</strike> <strike>122</strike> 121 bytes

```
b[99]={};main(l,c){for(;(c=getchar())<95u;)b[c]=(l+=c==10);for(c=47;++c<58;)b[c]&&printf("%c,%f\n",c,sqrt((l-b[c])*20));}
```

Compile & run with `gcc -w golf.c -lm && cat balls.txt | ./a.out`.

Comment: That's really great, sir! I didn't say that in my question, but I'd like you to know, that your example does not output anything, when character other than `0 ... 9` occurs in text file. Anyway, +1, because not pointing this out is my fault

Comment: @Jacajack No, any character is fine as long as it does not contain a character with ASCII code bigger than `_`. However, this could be fixed with one extra byte (`!=` instead of `<`).

Comment: Well, I used 'x' for testing. Nevermind. Your code's great :)

Comment: @Jacajack In the new version it's not a one character fix anymore, but I saved 3 more bytes :)

Comment: Nice! :) I'll take a look at what I can do with my code, when I come back home. I know it can be shortened a lot, but I don't want it to be a copy of yours :p

Answer (score 6):

## C -<s>194(-5)</s> <s>150</s> 137 bytes

*With a little bit more time and thinking, I golfed off 44 bytes*

 *Thanks to **orlp** for helping me to save 13 bytes*

I'll start with my C code:

```c
b[256]={},n,i=47;main(l,c){for(;~(c=getchar());n=c==95?l:n)b[c]=(l+=c==10);for(;++i<58;)b[i]&&printf("%d %f\n",i-48,sqrt((n-b[i])*20));}
```

And human readable version:

```c
//Throws many warnings, but lack of libraries is tolerated

/*
    c - current character
    l - line number (starts at 1)
    n - ground level
    i - iterator
    b - balls array
*/

b[256] = {}, n, i = 47; //That actually works, as long as you are using ASCII

main( l, c )
{
    for ( ;~( c = getchar( ) ); n = c == 95 ? l : n ) //Read stdin and search for ground
        b[c] = ( l += c == 10 ); //Increment lines counter on newlines, and save line numbers

    for ( ; ++i < 58; ) //Iterate through balls
        b[i] && printf( "%d %f\n", i - 48, sqrt( ( n - b[i] ) * 20 ) ); //Print out data    
}
```

Compile and run like that:
`gcc -o balls ballsgolf.c -lm && cat 1.txt | ./balls`

### Output

```
1 10.000000
2 10.000000
3 8.944272
4 7.745967
5 10.000000
```

Comment: Save 4 bytes: `~(c=getchar())` instead of `(c=getchar())!=EOF`.

Comment: @marinus That's what I had.

Comment: `if (x != -1)` is the same as `if (~x)` (on two's complement machines) because `~-1` is (uniquely) `0`. In C golf never use `while(cond)`, as `for(;cond;)` is just as long and provides more opportunities for golfing. In your example this can become `for(;~(c=getchar());n=c==95?l:n)b[c]=(l+=c==10);`.

Comment: @orlp I understand, thanks for advice :)

Comment: `l=1` can be circumvented by making `l` the first argument for `main`, as the C runtime passes the number of arguments to main as its first argument (`argc`), and when you call a program without any command line arguments (`./a.out`), then `argc = l = 1`. `n=0;` is unnecessary, as global integers are automatically initialized to 0. So just `n;` will suffice.

Comment: The `c=n;` is unnecessary if you rename the loop variable `n` in the second loop to `i`.

Comment: @orlp That's right. I don't know why, I was little bit afraid of not initializing variables with 0. Also, I thought that declaring variable like this in `for` loop would be invalid. `argc` stuff is whlole new level of trickiness, though. It's good to know things like these, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
smf-hT" _".e,b@*20-xd\_k2dC
smf@hT`M;.e,b@*20-xd\_k2dC
smf@T`M;.e,b@*20-xd\_k2dC
sm@#`M;.e,b@*20-xd\_k2dC
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%40%23%60M%3B.e%2Cb%40%2a20-xd%5C_k2dC&input=%5B%27++1+++++++++5++++++++++2++%27%2C%27++6++++++++++++++3++++++++%27%2C%27+++++4++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27__________________________%27%5D&debug=0)

Comment: [Fails if the last line is not the ground.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.e%2CR%40%2a20t-lQk2-bdP&input=%5B%22++1+++++++++5++++++++++2%22%2C%22+++++++++++++++++3%22%2C%22+++++4%22%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%2C%22__________________________%22%2C+%22%22%5D&debug=0)

Comment: @orlp Oh, I thought the ground level can only be in the last line.

Comment: [It still fails after your edit.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%23m%2CJ-d%22+_%22%40%2a20-xd%5C_xdJ2C&input=%5B%27++1+++++++++5++++++++++2++%27%2C%27+++++++++++++++++3++++++++%27%2C%27+++++4++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27__________________________%27%2C+%27%27%5D&debug=0)

Comment: @orlp [No, it doesn't](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%23m%2CJ-d%22+_%22%40%2a20-xd%5C_xdJ2C&input=%5B%27++1+++++++++5++++++++++2++%27%2C%27+++++++++++++++++3++++++++%27%2C%27+++++4++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%2C%27__________________________%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++%27%5D&debug=0)

Comment: Yes it does. I gave an input on which it fails, which is exactly one empty line after the underscores.

Comment: @orlp It was [in the rules](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/83792/7) that "You can add spaces, to fill empty lines, if that does help you."

Answer (score 3):

### Matlab, <s>100</s> <s>96</s> <s>89</s> 90  bytes

```
s=input('');X=find(s==95);for i=0:9
[x y]=find(s==48+i);if(x)[i sqrt(20*(X(1)-x))]
end
end
```

Many bytes saved thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

Input format:

```
['  1         9          2  ';'                 3        ';'     4                    ';'                          ';'                          ';'__________________________']
```

**Explanation:**

```
X=find(s==95)         -- finds '_', we'll need X(1) to determine max height
for i=0:9             -- loops through balls' numbers
[x y]=find(s==48+i)   -- finds the ball
if(x)                 -- if it is present
[i sqrt(20*(X(1)-x))] -- output its number and velocity
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 84 bytes

Version 6, 84 bytes: (Thanks to Leaky Nun!)

```
lambda a:[(c,(~-(len(a)-i)*20)**.5)for i,s in enumerate(a)for c in s if c.isdigit()]
```

Version 5, 91 bytes:

```
lambda a:[c+":"+str((~-(len(a)-i)*20)**.5)for i,s in enumerate(a)for c in s if c.isdigit()]
```

Version 4, 92 bytes:

```
lambda i:[c+":"+str((~-(len(i)-n)*20)**.5)for n in range(len(i))for c in i[n]if c.isdigit()]
```

Version 3, 99 bytes:

```
def r(i):x=len(i);print([c+":"+str((~-(x-n)*20)**.5)for n in range(x)for c in i[n] if c.isdigit()])
```

Version 2, 102 bytes:

```
def r(i):
 n=len(i)
 for l in i:
  for c in l:
   if c.isdigit():print(c+":"+str((~-n*20)**.5))
  n-=1
```

The above versions take an array of strings as input.

Version 1, 140 bytes:

```
with open(input(),"r")as i:
 n=sum(1for l in i);i.seek(0)
 for l in i:
  for c in l:
   if c.isdigit():print(c+":"+str((~-n*20)**.5))
  n-=1
```

This takes the directory of the file as input from the user.

Comment: `1 for l in i` -> `1for l in i`

Comment: @LeakyNun, does that trick work with all keywords and numbers?

Comment: I believe so. Also, `(n-1)*20` -> `~-n*20`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you could probably save a lot of byte by taking an array of strings as input instead, or just define a function taking an array of strings.

Comment: Hold on. Doesn't Python3 require parentheses with the `print` call?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could make this into one line: `for c in l:if c.isdigit():print c+":"+str((~-n*20)**.5)`

Comment: @TuukkaX, yeah you're right. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @LeakyNun, do you know if I am allowed to take an array as input?

Comment: @Dopapp I think so. The MATL answer does it as well.

Comment: @LeakyNun No it doesn't work for all keywords and numbers in Python 2. It specifically does not work for keywords starting with an `e`, because then the Python tokenizer will attempt to parse it as floating point scientific notation (e.g. `1e5`). Example that fails: `f = lambda n:-1if n<0else 1`. An example that fails in both Python version is `0or 1`, because the tokenizer thinks `0o` starts an octal number.

Comment: Try `enumerate`.

Comment: @LeakyNun, do you have an idea of how to improve my last answer which uses `enumerate`?

Comment: `lambda a:[(c,(~-(len(a)-i)*20)**.5)for i,s in enumerate(a)for c in s if c.isdigit()]` Oh, also it doesn't work if the ground level is not the last line.

Comment: @LeakyNun, why would that not work if the ground level is not the last line? Doesn't `if c.isdigit()` take care of that?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 84 bytes

```
lambda x:[[i,(20*x[x.find(i):x.find('_')].count('\n'))**.5]for i in x if i.isdigit()]
```

An anonymous function that accepts input by argument as a multi-line string with all empty lines filled with spaces, and returns an array where each element is of the form [ball number, speed].

**How it works**

```
lambda x                      Function with input x
...for i in x if i.isdigit()  Loop through all characters i in x for which i is a digit,
                              and hence one of the balls
x[x.find(i):x.find('_')]      Slice x to give the substring between the ball and the ground
....count('\n')               Count the number of newlines in the substring to give the
                              height of the ball
(20*...)**.5                  Calculate the speed of the ball as it hits the ground
[i,...]                       Package the ball number and speed into a list
:[...]                        Return all ball-speed pairs as a list with elements [ball
                              number, speed]
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/aPDp8i)

Comment: In this case, I think, it's code snippet rather than full standalone Python script, isn't it?

Comment: @Jacajack This is in fact a function, not a snippet, which is allowed by [default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/55526). In Python, lambda functions are functions without a name which can assigned to a variable and then called when needed; you could write `f = MyAnswer`, and then call using `f(x)`. There is a consensus that there is [no need to name lambdas](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9032/55526). Nice challenge, by the way!

Comment: Sure, I just thought lambdas were assumed to be code snippets here (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1146/55729). I guess everything is fine, then. Thank you for your opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 93

*Edit* 2 bytes saved thx @Jacajack

A function with a multiline string as input parameter. Output is not sorted (as this in not requested)

```
a=>[...a].reverse().map(c=>c>'Z'?b=i:c<' '?++i:c>' '&&console.log(c,Math.sqrt((i-b)*20)),i=0)
```

**Test**

```js
F=
a=>[...a].reverse().map(c=>c>'Z'?b=i:c<' '?++i:c>' '&&console.log(c,Math.sqrt((i-b)*20)),i=0)

function test()
{
  F(I.value);
}

test()
```

```css
#I { height: 12em; width: 30em}
```

```html
<textarea id=I>
    
 
  1         5          2
                 3
     4


__________________________




</textarea>
<button onclick="test()"></button>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `sqrt(x)` be shorter than `pow(x,.5)`?

Comment: @Jacajack yes thanks I don't know how that slipped off my mind